# Specify log file for docker container

Tags: docker, logging, docker-compose

I have this set of services I wish to do some logging for. Some services are running a node app, so the output is directly visible in the `docker logs` command.
However, a couple are different. Let's use my Java application as an example. It's running in a wrapper but the logging is written to a log file instead of `STDOUT`.

How can I hook the file as the `docker logs` output?

ps. The other app is an PHP app on a Nginx server, also with it's own logging file.

-UPDATE
The application is a Java application (.jar file) running in Java Service Wrapper from Tanuki. The built JAR has a Log4j logger writing via a `DailyRollingFileAppender` to `logs/server.log`. The Wrapper itself has output which I ignore via `>/dev/null 2>&1`. I just added to following line to the Dockerfile.

`RUN ln -sf /dev/stdout /opt/myserver/logs/server.log`

This is not working though. No output is send when I use `docker-compose up myserver`

Answer (score 4):

Link log file(s) to `stdout/stderr`. For example in your `Dockerfile`:

```
RUN ln -sf /dev/stdout /<path>/logfile.log \
    && ln -sf /dev/stderr /<path>/errors-logfile.log
```

Comment: This does not seem to work. Could this be that running the application will prevent this or something?

Comment: "It doesn't work" is not a report - how can someone replicate your problem from this report. Please be provide all details of your app in your question, when you need exact solution for your case. Generally, this approach works - it is used for example in the official nginx docker file - https://github.com/nginxinc/docker-nginx/blob/baa050df601b5e798431a9db458e16f53b1031f6/mainline/stretch/Dockerfile

Comment: Sorry for the incomplete reply. I will update the question.

Answer (score 2):

I found it. Apparently you can write logs from docker containers via

`RUN ln -sf /proc/1/fd/1 /opt/myserver/logs/server.log`

in your Dockerfile